# Link to website from lightbox image being display & display order when multiples

Tags: lightbox2

Hi our implementation has been quite simple, we have numerous high resolution photographs of WW2 soldiers memorials which we have had to purchase.

Our project involves photo documenting the entire cemetery.

Problem 1)
So when the map is clicked for a particular grave location , we display a pre-watermarked photo with more information beside it.  Works a treat !

I would like to have it so that if the displayed image isf clicked on, the user would be directed to  the website in the UK that actually sells the originals of the image.
We have bought a copy and are using it on our NFP website but I would like to repay the work that the original photographers undertook (thousands of images) and let people buy their own copy.

Problem 2)
If we have multiple interments in one grave, we display a "memorial card for each person".
There is easy instruction on how to do this however the order seems to be it uses the last of the 3 images first   ie href xxx href yyy href zzz  over 3 rows would display zzz before the others.  As there maybe multiple memorials involved I want to be able to display them in the order they physically appear from left to right.  Is there a way to dictate the order other positionally entering them into the html ?  (ie image_1 image_2 image_3  processed in the numeric order) ?

Cheers for any assistance

Not been able to work out solutions as to adding clickable links to the lightbox code
normall html link doesnt work that I could establish  plsu I want it to be particularly for right click function